# I am trying to make a simple App multiplies user input value in Android studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just want to make a simple app that multiply two different user inputs, and shows the result in resultview method on onClick listener which is the "Calculate" button. Could you guys show me the block of code could do that, i've already declared the widgets and stuff, all i need is the multiply method.. please help I am now Programmer, and trying to learn. Thanks, your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.alexm.percentcal;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button cal_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cal_button);
    final EditText percentBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentBox);
    final EditText valuebox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valueBox);
    final TextView resultview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    cal_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

    }


  }

}
```

Comment: Please if you see a mistake or a bug by all means please correct it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code inside of onClick of `cal_button`

```
int val1 = Integer.parseInt(percentBox.getText());
int val2 = Integer.parseInt(valueBox.getText());

//as you can not set int value to TextView, so convert it to string.
resultView.setText(String.valueOf(val1*val2));
```

Comment: You probably won't be able to upvote the answer since your reputation is < 15. Also you should read how to ask questions on stackoverflow or your account will be banned since you're not learning anything from downvotes.

Comment: Where can i read how to ask question or how to increase my reputation? btw i greatly appreciate your answer.